# Issues after Updating to Marshmallow

Tags: ota-update, 6.0-marshmallow, motorola-moto-g3

I have a 3rd generation Motorola Moto G. I recently updated it to Marshmallow. After doing this, at first I did not encounter any issues but soon afterwards, I started to experience many issues with Android, including:

- The pattern lock is absent
- I am unable to connect my phone to my computer
- The button to factory reset the device is greyed-out
- The drop-down notification panel is absent

How can I correct these issues?

Comment: Can you add screenshots please to show each behaviour?

Comment: Can you factory reset by pressing volume down + power when starting the device?. Marshmallow caused no problems for me

Comment: Thankyou so much. I got it right by rebooting

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems. I followed the reset device in Recovery Mode instructions here, and it solved them for me -

https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/4596836?hl=en

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Otherwise, your answer becomes useless in case the link dies. For further hints, please see: [How do I write a good answer](/help/how-to-answer).